# Animated GIF larger than source images

Tags: optimization, imagemagick, gif, animated-gif

I'm using imagemagick to create an animated GIF out of ~60 JPG 640x427px photos. The combined size of the JPGs is about 4MB.

However, the output GIF is ~12MB. Is there a reason why the GIF is considerably bigger? Can I conceivably achieve a GIF size of ~4MB?

The command I'm using is:

```
convert -channel RGB # no improvement in size 
   -delay 2x10 \
   -size 640 \
   -loop 0 \
   -dispose Background # no improvement in size 
   -layers Optimize # about 2MB improvement 
   portrait/*.jpg portrait.gif
```

Using `gifsicle` didn't seem to improve either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPEG achieves it's compression through a (lossy) transform, where an 16x16 / 8x8 block of pixels is transformed to frequency representation and then quantized. Instead of selecting e.g. 256 levels (i.e. 8 bits) of red/green/blue per component, JPEG can ignore some frequency components, or use just 1 or 2 bits to represent them.

GIF on the other hand works by identifying repeated patterns from a *paletted image* (upto 256 entries), which occur *exactly* in the previously encoded/decoded stream. Both because of the JPEG compression, and the source of the images typically encoded by JPEG (natural full color), the probability of (long) exact matches is quite low.

60 RGB images with the size 640x427 is about 16 million pixels. To represent that much in 4 MB, requires a compression of 2 bits per pixel. To achieve this with GIF would require a very lossy algorithm, that would select (vector) quantization of true color pixels not to the closest pixel in the target GIF palette, but based also on the fact how good dictionary of code words this particular selection will make. The dictionary builds slowly and to achieve 2 bits/pixel, the average length of the decoded code word would have to map to 5.5 matching pixels in the close neighborhood.

By contrast, imagemagick has been able to compress the 16 million pixels (each selected from a palette of 256 elements) to 75% already!

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. The next question goes without saying -- is there a lossy format of comparable performance to JPEG that supports animation?

Comment: Google for MJPEG. M stands for Motion and can be implemented both by concatenating JPG-files (Stereographic "multi-jpeg" is an example) and by encoding the delta between images (original MJPEG).

Answer (score 2):

JPG is lossy compression.
GIF is lossless compression.

A better comparison would be to convert all the source images to GIF first, then combine them..

First google hit for GIF compression is http://ezgif.com/optimize which claims lossy GIF compresion, might work for you but I offer no warranty as I haven't tried it.